# COUNT(1) Over() is taking time to get the total records count in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2012, paging

I have table with 250,000 records. There is one SP where I am getting those records as per paging. Along with paging I need to get the total record count as well. But when I add `COUNT(1) Over()` in SP it is taking time. And when I remove it with hardcoded value as 100 then SP results are coming in 1 sec. Is there any other way to get total records count?

Comment: What happens when you just do `select count(1) from tableName` in a separate query?

Comment: It works but in this case I need to execute same query twice. Once for getting Total records Count and then for getting actual results. I don't want to run it twice as it is having many joins and where conditions.